# Haskell Typeclass issue

Tags: haskell

I am having a hard time solving problem 6 from http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/Classes/14S/cis425/assignments/hw7.html . So far I have done following:

```
    data Comparison = Less | Equal | Greater
          deriving (Show, Eq)

compareInt :: Int -> Int -> Comparison
compareInt x y =
    if x < y then Less else if x > y then Greater else Equal

compareChar :: Char -> Char -> Comparison
compareChar x y =
    if x < y then Less else if x > y then Greater else Equal

class Comp a where
  (?=) :: a -> a -> Comparison

-- Integer comparison
instance Comp Int where
  (?=) x y = compareInt x y

-- Character comparison
instance Comp Char where
  (?=) x y = compareChar x y

-- Lists are compared element by element
instance Comp a => Comp [a] where
  (?=) [] [] = Equal
  (?=) (x:xs) [] = Greater
  (?=) [] (y:ys) = Less
  (?=) (x:xs) (y:ys) =
    if (x ?= y) /= Equal then x ?= y else xs ?= ys

-- Pairs are compared by first element, then by second element
instance (Comp a, Comp b) => Comp (a, b) where
  (?=) (x1, x2) (y1, y2) = if (x1 ?= y1) /= Equal then x1 ?= y1 else x2 ?= y2    

f x y = let
        xx = (length x, x)
        yy = (length y, y)
        in ( xx ?= yy )  

data CompD a = MakeCompD (a -> a -> Comparison)

-- Integer comparison
dCompInt :: CompD Int
dCompInt = MakeCompD compInt where
    compInt x y = (?=) x y

-- List comparison
dCompList :: CompD a -> CompD [a]
dCompList d = MakeCompD compList where
    compList []     []     = Equal
    compList (x:xs) []     = Greater
    compList []     (y:ys) = Less
    compList (x:xs) (y:ys) =
          if ((?=) x y) /= Equal 
        then ((?=) x y) 
        else ((?=) (xs) (ys))

-- Pair Comparison
dCompPair :: CompD a -> CompD b -> CompD (a, b)
dCompPair da db = MakeCompD compPair where
    compPair (x1, y1) (x2, y2) =
          if ((?=) x1 y1) /= Equal
        then (?=) x1 y1
        else (?=) x2 y2    

--b.
--(?=) dCompPair (length "Hello", "Hello") (length "World", "World")
--(?=) dCompInt               length "Hello" length "World"
--(?=) dCompString        "Hello"              "World"
--(?=) dCompChar            'H'                  'W'

--c.
--f :: [Char]->[Char]->comparison
```

But I get errors.

Comment: How about only showing that part of the code which throws error and explaining in the question what type of error you get.

Comment: face compile error and not sure how to solve it.

Comment: If that is actually what your indentation looks like, that would be the problem. A lot of it is wrong (`if` alignment, `let .. in` alignment, etc)

Comment: You'll find things easier if you write a small section of code, compile, add another bit of code, compile, etc. That way, if you get a compilation error, you'll have a better idea what the problem is. And if you can't figure it out, it will be easier to create an an MWE (A Minimal Working Example, i.e. a small amount of code that demonstrates the problem, but without any additional complexity or dependencies which will make resolution harder.

If you need help in future, please provide an MWE and the exact compiler error messages.

Answer (score 6):

I could identify three issues:

You over-indented the data definition (although that might have been an artefact from the StackOverflow editor)

```
data Comparison = Less | Equal | Greater
      deriving (Show, Eq)
```

You omitted a proper context for `dCompList`:

```
-- dCompList :: CompD a -> CompD [a]
dCompList :: Comp a => CompD a -> CompD [a]
```

And finally there seems to be something wrong with your `dCompPair` since it ignores its arguments. But this is the fix to make it compile (but it's probably not what you intended).

```
dCompPair :: (Comp a, Comp b) => CompD a -> CompD b -> CompD (a, b)
dCompPair _ _ = MakeCompD compPair where
    compPair (x1, y1) (x2, y2) =
          if ((?=) x1 x2) /= Equal    -- The comparisons here
        then (?=) x1 x2               -- were falsely comparing
        else (?=) y1 y2               -- x1 with y1 and x2 with y2
```

I made it explicity for you that you were ignoring `da` and `db` by replacing them with underscores. You probably want to fix that, I think.

Comment: Great! Can you please edit it to include it everything so that I can mark your answer as correct!

Comment: @user3682619: I provided you with all the syntactical errors in your code. I don't know what is still missing for you.

Comment: The exercise is about using explicit dictionaries instead of type classes, so you don't need a context containing `Comp`. Instead you have a `CompD`(ictionary), which has its own definition for `?=` (to extract the comparison function from the dictionary), so the class and instances should be commented out if you want it to compile.